# Why do I have to click on webpage to active javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio

Why do I have to click on the page once after every refresh to activate the audio? I cannot figure out what happened. The audio player doesn't work after I refresh the page.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="musical-container">
  <div class="musicHolder">
    Mouse over Image to play Music 1
    <audio preload="auto">
      <source src="https://www.lucedigitale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/danosongs_001.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="https://www.lucedigitale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/danosongs_001.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      Your browser does not support this audio format.
    </audio>
    <img src="https://www.lucedigitale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/audio.png">
  </div>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <div class="musicHolder">
    Mouse over Image to play Music 2
    <audio preload="auto">
      <source src="https://www.lucedigitale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/danosongs_002.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="https://www.lucedigitale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/danosongs_002.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      Your browser does not support this audio format.
    </audio>
    <img src="https://www.lucedigitale.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/audio.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.musical-container img').hover(function() {
    $(this).prev()[0].play()
  }, function() {
    $(this).prev()[0].pause()
  })
})
```

Comment: This is a feature of modern browsers. Audio will only be played if the user has first interacted with the page in some manner (mouse click, typing etc). You cannot play a sound before the interaction has occurred. More details: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Please remove the java tag.